# SQL Server select all URLs from column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select all links from a column, the column is a Html Content (page)

This is what i have so far

```
declare @col nvarchar(MAX) ;
set @col = (select Content from bg_landingPage)

select SUBSTRING(@col, LEN(LEFT(@col, PATINDEX ('http://', @col))) + 1, LEN(@col) - LEN(LEFT(@col, 
          CHARINDEX ('/', @col))) - LEN(RIGHT(@col,LEN(@col) - CHARINDEX (' ', @col))) - 1)
```

Since the column (Html Page) could have more then one link i get this

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

How can I get the results in a one column table way

LINK

---

http://exemple1
http://exemple2

Thank you.

Comment: may not really be a solution, but you should reconsider the table scheme if there are multiple values in one column - this violates the [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: What is your expected output?  Note that SQL Server has fairly poor regex support.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen really one can add existing .net regex via CLR integration . MS choosed not to add it by default due to perfomance considerations AFAIK.

Comment: Your links don't work. This is the reason people on SO don't like links to data/code etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is caused by multiple records in bg_landingpage.

try the code below instead.

```
select top 1 @col = Content from bg_landingPage
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I've done is create a console application and did all the processing in C#.

The 2nd method that i've tested using SQL commands, is use a Cursor